# Convert written text in columns to numbers in R

Tags: r

Newbie-sh with R.

**CHALLENGE:** I have this data frame with a number of variables in columns (see below).  I need to convert the text  of "$ TIMEPT  : chr" to a numeric value and do some math.

```
$ SUBJ  : chr  "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
$ VISIT   : chr  "0" "12" "34" "84" ...
$ TIMEPT  : chr "Within 15 minutes prior to stopping infusion" "Within 5 minutes prior to stopping infusion" "5 minutes post infusion" "15 minutes post infusion" ...
```

**MY 2 APPROACHES:**

1.

```
df$TIMEPT <-replace (df$TIMEPT, df$TIMEPT == "Within 15 minutes
prior to dosing", 0)
```

This approach only worked for the first set of text I tried
    converting the TIMEPT variable as a factor:

2.

```
df$TIMEPT <- within(df, TIMEPT <- df$TIMEPT <- factor(TIMEPT, labels
= c(0, 1,2,3.92,4.08, 4.25, 4.5, 5, 6, 7, 10)))
```

This approach (2) created nested tables of all variables (then the df became larger and more complex). Converting these factors to numbers did not work using the following expression:

```
df$TIMEPT <- as.numeric(as.numeric(df$TIMEPT))
```

**QUESTION**
- How could I convert such "long" text TIMEPT into numerical values?

**EXPECTED OUTCOME**

AN over simplification would be:

SUBJID    VISIT   TIMEPT
1   1        0     0
2   2        0     1

3   3        0     2

4   4        0     3
...

**NOTE:**
The text in $TIMEPT have similar numerical values across the df. For example the text specifies "within 5 min prior", "before 5 min", "5 min post" ... As such, numerical parsing might not work (I'll try as suggested below)

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I have a hard time to interpret your question. Would you be able to clarify what you are trying to achieve? If possible, would you provide a minimal sample data and show your expected outcome? That will help SO users to give you a hand.

Comment: To clarify my question:

Comment: To clarify my question: How to convert the text into a numerical value? The expected outcome should be: $ TIMEPT  : num 0, 1,2,3.92,4.08 ...  The outcome will be used to graph per $ SUBJID , $ VISIT  and $Dependent variable (not shown above).

Comment: You can [edit] your clarifications straight into your question.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
df$newvariable<-readr::parse_number(df$TIMET)
```

it should extract only the numbers from the character string.

example:

```
c<-data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), y=c("10 mins", "20 mins", "30 mins", "40 mins", "50 mins", "60 Minutes", "70 mins", "80 mins", "90 minutes"))
c$y<-as.character(c$y)
c$t<-readr::parse_number(c$y)


c
  x          y  t
1 1    10 mins 10
2 2    20 mins 20
3 3    30 mins 30
4 4    40 mins 40
5 5    50 mins 50
6 6 60 Minutes 60
7 7    70 mins 70
8 8    80 mins 80
9 9 90 minutes 90
```